Measure theoretical completion preserves inclusion
I'm reading this answer, where they prove that $$\overline{\sigma(M\times N)}=\overline{\sigma(\overline{M}\times\overline{N})},\tag1$$where $M,N$ are $\sigma$-algebras and $M\times N=\{A\times B: A\in M, B\in N\}$. Moreover, if $(X, M,\mu)$ is a measure space, then $\overline{M}=\{E\cup F: E\in M \text{ and }F\subset G\in M\text{ such that }\mu(G)=0\}$ is the completion of $M$ with respect to $\mu$. The measure which is the extension of $\mu$ to $\overline{M}$ is denoted $\overline{\mu}$ and one can show this measure is unique.
To show the dependence of the measure more clearly, one could also adopt the notation $M_\mu$ for the completion of $M$ and the product $\sigma$-algebra to be $M\otimes N$. Then $(1)$ reads $$(M\otimes N)_{\mu\times \nu} = (M_\mu \otimes N_\nu)_{\overline{\mu}\times \overline{\nu}}.\tag2$$I don't mind which notation is used.
Now, in the answer, they claim that $$\sigma(M\times N)\subseteq\overline{\sigma(\overline{M}\times\overline{N})}\implies \overline{\sigma(M\times N)}\subseteq\overline{\sigma(\overline{M}\times\overline{N})}.\tag3$$
I struggle with this claim. Here's my attempt at showing the implication. I follow Folland's exposition in his real analysis text.
$\overline{\mu}$ agrees with $\mu$ on $M$, same for $\overline{\nu}$ and $\nu$ on $N$. So $\overline{\mu}\times\overline{\nu}$ agrees with $\mu\times\nu$ on rectangles and consequently on the algebra of finite disjoint union of rectangles. Do they also agree on $\sigma(M\times N)$? This is partly where I'm stuck, since I guess I have to invoke Caratheodory's extension theorem to show the two measures agree on $\sigma(M\times N)$, but this requires the measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ to be $\sigma$-finite. It feels strange that $(3)$ would rely on $\sigma$-finiteness.
Anyway, what I'm trying to show is that every $\mu\times\nu$-null set is also a $\overline{\mu}\times\overline{\nu}$-null set. Suppose this is true. As shown in the link, we actually have $M\times N\subseteq\sigma(\overline{M}\times\overline{N})\subseteq\overline{\sigma(\overline{M}\times\overline{N})}$ and so $\sigma(M\times N)\subseteq\sigma(\overline{M}\times\overline{N})$, so every set in $\overline{\sigma(M\times N)}$, which can be written as $E\cup F$ where $E\in \sigma(M\times N)\subseteq\sigma(\overline{M}\times\overline{N})$ and $F$ is a subset of a $\mu\times\nu$-null (which would imply it is also subset of a $\overline{\mu}\times\overline{\nu}$-null set), is a set in $\overline{\sigma(\overline{M}\times\overline{N})}$. But how do I show every $\mu\times\nu$-null set is also a $\overline{\mu}\times\overline{\nu}$-null set?

Suppose $A$ is a sigma algebra, $B$ is a complete sigma algebra, and $A\subseteq B$. Let $\bar{A}$ denote the completion of $A$.  Is it true that $\bar{A}\subseteq B$ ?

@Medo well, "complete sigma algebra" is with respect to a measure. So how are the measures on $A$ and $B$ related?

The measure on $A$ is a restriction to $A$ of the measure on $B$.
